# Emulate an int in python

Tags: python, reference, int, built-in

I want to define an object which has the exact same behavior as an int, with a few tiny differences. Consider the class

```
class MyInt:
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.num = num
```

I need to enable the following behavior: when `MyInt` is assigned to another variable, the operation results to assigning `MyInt.num` instead of the whole class, i.e.

```
i = MyInt(10)
a = i
print(type(a)) # <class 'int'>
print(a)       # 10
```

In other words, `a=i` results in `a= i.num`. All other functionality of `MyInt` should be exactly the same as `int` and applied on `MyInt.num`, e.g. `i += 1` should be equivalent to `i.num +=1`

I guess that this can be accomplished by making `MyInt` inherit from `int` and making use of `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`. However, I am not  sure what method is used to fetch the value of a variable in python so that I can achieve the desired functionality.

Disclaimer: I need this so that I can modify a variable globally inside a function. I am aware this is not recommended, but it is my only option.  Also I cannot use `global`.

Comment: You can't do that. There are no hooks in Python that let you adjust assignments.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible at all. What's wrong with `a = i.num` (in the usage code)? Also you could let `a` remain a `MyInt` and adjust printing etc. so it'll be invisible to the code using the class.

Comment: Also, in many cases if you need features the language doesn't implement, you're thinking about it in a wrong way. You might want to add the actual use case (why do you need such a class?), so people here could make proposals that are actually possible.

Comment: Thanks for help. The actual use case is storing `i.num` in a numpy array of type `np.uint8`. Since there seems to be no way to adjust assignments, is it possible to use hacky workaround in which I overload the cast method for `MyInt` to `np.uint8`?

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that. There are no hooks in Python that let you adjust assignments.

There are any number of ways of binding an object, and to Python, *there is no difference, **at all***, between `i = MyInt(10)` and `a = i`. Both are assignments where the result of the expression on the right-hand side are executed *first*, then a reference to the result is stored under a specific name. Since `i` produces the a reference to the same object already produced by `MyInt(10)`, you end up with 2 references, with different names, to a single instance.

But `[i]` also stores a reference, now in a list object. So does `for target_name in (i, i):` (3 references, first in a tuple with two references, then `target_name`, which is bound twice like this when the loop executes and nothing exits the loop early). I count at least [8 different ways of binding objects](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) in Python.

You *can* make `MyInt` work like an integer in most cases; there are [a number of special methods to emulate numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) that let you accomplish this. There is even a [`numbers.Integral` abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral) you can use as a starting point. These provide you with a number of those special methods pre-implemented, but you do have to still implement a number of abstract methods, however:

```
>>> from numbers import Integral
>>> sorted(Integral.__abstractmethods__)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__ceil__', '__eq__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__neg__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__']
```

Since any subclass that doesn't can't be instantiated, these give you instant feedback on whether or not you missed any of those methods.

Methods already provided are:

```
>>> from numbers import Number
>>> sorted(n for n in dir(Integral) if n not in Integral.__abstractmethods__.union(dir(Number)))
['__bool__', '__complex__', '__divmod__', '__float__', '__index__', '__rdivmod__', '__rsub__', '__sub__', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
```

and you really want to provide a suitable [`__hash__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).